# fast algorithm for computing 1/d?(SRT, goldsmidt, newton raphson,...)

Tags: algorithm, fpga

I want to find a fast algorithm for computing 1/d , where d is double ( albeit it can be converted to integer) what is the best algorithm of many algorithms(SRT , goldschmidt,newton raphson, ...)?I'm writing my program in c language.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Most processors have either a division instruction or a reciprocal instruction. Why exactly do you want to write an algorithm? Your criterion is “fast” but anything you write yourself is never going to be as fast as the hardware implementation for either.

Comment: My program must be implemented in fpga and in fpga there is no division , I must find a fast procedure!

Comment: @Abdolah

Are you trying to synthesize FPGA logic from highlevel programming language such as C/C++?  If so, I can see why you would be interested in knowing fastest hardware implementation of a division algorithm in FPGAs.  Generally, for FPGAs, the vendor provided megafunctions will give you the fastest performance on a particular fpga device.  The vendors may even tell you what algorithm they use.  You would have to see what kind of support they have for division in their tools to synthesize highlevel languages to fpga logic. Maybe if you tag your question with "hdl"  you may get more hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked it from someone and I get my answer:

So, you can't add a hardware divider to the FPGA then? Or fast reciprocal support?

Anyway it depends. Does it have fast multiplication? If not, well, that's a problem, you could only implement the slow methods then.

If you have fast multiplication and IEEE floats, you can use the weird trick I linked to in my previous post with a couple of refinement steps. That's really just Newton–Raphson division with a simpler calculation for the initial approximation (but afaik it still only takes 3 refinements for single-precision floats, just like the regular initial approximation). Fast reciprocal support works that way too - give a fast initial approximation (handling the exponent right and getting significant bits from a lookup table, if you get 12 significant bits that way you only need one refinement step for single-precision or, 13 are enough to get 2 steps for double-precision) and optionally have instructions that help implement the refinement step (like AMD's PFRCPIT1 and PFRCPIT2), for example to calculate Y = (1 - D*X) and to calculate X + X * Y.

Even without those tricks Newton–Raphson division is still not bad, with the linear approximation it takes only 4 refinements for double-precision floats, but it also takes some annoying exponent adjustments to get in the right range first (in hardware that wouldn't be half as annoying).

Goldschmidt division is, afaik, roughly equivalent in performance and might have a slightly less complex implementation. It's really the same sort of deal - trickery with the exponent to get in the right range, the "2 - something" estimation trick (which is rearranged in Newton-Raphson division, but it's really the same thing), and doing the refinement step until all the bits are right. It just looks a little different.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest program is: `double result = 1 / d`;

Comment: My program is in C but then it must be implemented with fpga and in fpga there is no division , so I must choose one of these algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

CPU:s already use a root finding iterative algorithm like the ones you describe, to find the reciprocal 1/d. So you should find it difficult to beat it using a software implementation of the same algorithm.

If you have few/known denominators then try a lookup table. This is the usual approach for even slower functions such as trig functions.

Otherwise: just compute 1/d. It will be the fastest you can do. And there is an endless list of things you can do to speed up arithmetic if you have to

- use 32 bit (single) instead of 64bit (double) precision. FP Division on takes a number of cycles proportional to the number of bits.
- vectorize the operations. For example I believe you can compute four 32bit float divisions in parallel with SSE2, or even more in parallel by doing it on the GPU.

Comment: I'm writing a bit of a large programme ,which in somewhere there is division , but divisions must be converted to division algorithm(instead of 1/d) so i want to know the fastest algorithm for it.

Comment: And there are alwready two answers here that explain that an algorithm for computing 1/d will not be faster than simply computing 1/d. Also: I doubt the divisions are really the bottleneck in your program.